# "World's Hardest Easy Geometry Problem"

Tags: geometry, triangles, angle

This question is a "corollary" (if you will) to the [World's Hardest Easy Geometry Problem](http://thinkzone.wlonk.com/MathFun/Triangle.htm) (external website). Formally, this is called **Langley's Problem**. The objective of that problem was to solve for angle $x^{\circ}$, with the given angles of $10^{\circ}, 70^{\circ}, 60^{\circ}, 20^{\circ}$. Someone presented a [solution](http://blog.drscottfranklin.net/2013/12/13/worlds-hardest-easy-geometry-problem/) to that problem. Here's also a rather [colorful and interactive solution](http://agutie.homestead.com/files/LangleyProblem.html) to a problem like this, but with different angles.

Now, I wanted to generalize this problem, replacing the angles of $10^{\circ}, 70^{\circ}, 60^{\circ}, 20^{\circ}$ with angles of $W^{\circ}, X^{\circ}, Y^{\circ}, Z^{\circ}$, respectively (see below picture).

[image]

How can we derive an analytical expression of angle $x^{\circ}$, in terms of $W^{\circ}, X^{\circ}, Y^{\circ}, Z^{\circ}$?

Comment: Coordinatize, and calculate approximately.

Comment: That might work for the original problem with fixed degrees. But I'm not sure if placing the triangle on the coordinate grid would work for arbitrary angles $w^{\circ}, x^{\circ}, y^{\circ}, z^{\circ}$.

Comment: You use $x^\circ$ for two distinct angles in your diagram...

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I changed it to capital $X^{\circ}$ then, to make the distinction, along with capital $W^{\circ},Y^{\circ},Z^{\circ}$.

Comment: I don't have a reference to hand, but I'd swear I remember an article either in the AMM or the Intelligencer about generalizations of the problem with 'nice' angles.  Digging around on the web suggests that this is called "Langley's Problem" but doesn't turn up what I'm thinking of...

Comment: I got a good chuckle from the inclusion of "This figure is drawn to scale".

Comment: I think the problem is more neatly stated without point C. We can just draw a quadrilateral and its diagonals, give four angles at the bottom, and say "find all the angles". Or put $|\overline{AB}|=1$ and say "solve this 
quadrilateral".

Comment: See Triangles and Quadrilaterals Revisited. Part 2: The Solution
R. A. Diamond and G. A. Georgiou
Mathematics in School
Vol. 30, No. 5 (Nov., 2001), pp. 11-13

Comment: Langley's Problem only works for those specific angles. The general case has no simple solution. ([This Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langley%E2%80%99s_Adventitious_Angles) has a nice picture and a solution of Langley's Problem.)

Comment: @StevenStadnicki This problem is not by Langley but, according to the link in the OP, by Schor. (Langley's is the same but with w=20°, x=60°, y=50°, z=30°.)

Answer (score 7):

Well, I'll give a guide to follow, not a final expression.
I called you unknown angle as $\alpha_9$ (in order not to mess, because you have a big $X$ and a small $x$).

Since you know $x$ and $y$ then you know $\alpha_4$.

Since you know $x$, $w$, $z$ and $y$ then you know $\alpha_1$.

Since you know $x$ and $\alpha_5$ then you know $\alpha_3$.

Since you know $w$ and $\alpha_5$ then you know $\alpha_6$.

Then you end up with a system of $4$ equations:
$$
\begin{cases}
\alpha_1+\alpha_2+\alpha_7=\pi \\
\alpha_4+\alpha_8+\alpha_9=\pi \\
\alpha_2+\alpha_3+\alpha_9=\pi\\
\alpha_6+\alpha_7+\alpha_8=\pi
\end{cases} 
$$
with $4$ unknowns: $\alpha_2, \alpha_7, \alpha_8, \alpha_9$.
And $\alpha_9$ is what you are looking for.


[image]

Comment: It seems to me that using only relations between the angles results in an underdetermined system of linear equations.

Comment: @ZhenLin - Start with line segment $\overline{AB}$ and draw lines upwards from A, making angles $x$ and $x+w$ with $\overline{AB}$, and from B, making angles $y$ and $y+z$ with it; all points are then determined.

Comment: That's not what I mean. If you actually use the geometry of the plane then there is no problem.

Comment: Zhen Lin is correct, the 4x4 linear system here is underdetermined, and one needs to find another independent equation from the geometry to resolve the problem. To see this, take the first equation, add the second equation, and subtract the fourth equation. What you end out with is an equation of the form $\alpha_2 + \alpha_9 = [\text{known value}]$, which is of the same form as the third equation.

Comment: But in this case the problem is that the matrix associated with the system of linear equations in four unknowns $\alpha_2, \alpha_7, \alpha_8$ and $\alpha_9$ given by \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} is not invertible.

Answer (score 5):

I have found the equation!

I first tried to insert the latex equation directly here, but that was ugly so I rendered it separately and inserted an image instead:
[image: equation for x]

Comment: Now, how was this expression derived? :)

Comment: My first attempt at solving it, I used only easy things like sum of all angles in triangle is $\pi$ and so on, but I couldn't solve it that way, so I decided to set the AB line to 1 and then write down what the other lines are in respect to that, when I had an expression for $a_8$, I wrote a computer program that expanded the expression to be in terms of the angles instead of the line lengths. The expression before the expansion was: $\arccos \left(\frac{DE^2 + IE^2 - DI^2}{2*DE*IE}\right)$

Answer (score 2):

There is in principle no problem in obtaining an *expression* for the top angle in terms of the bottom ones. Let the unlabelled intersection point in the picture be $I$. Let the bottom side be $1$. We can use the Sine Law to find $AI$ and $BI$. We can also find $AD$, and $BE$, and now we know $ID$ and $IE$, so we can solve for the mystery angle.

This does not result in a *nice* expression for the mystery angle, but it is an expression.

Comment: This problem can be solved using geometry without also using trig.

Comment: This is the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

If one draws a perpendicular line from A and extends line DE to an intersection at, say X, the two resultant triangles allow the equal angles XEA and AEB to be determined at 40 degrees. Angle BED is then 100 degrees and 'x' is 30 degrees.

Thinking outside the triangle(s)?

Comment: only for 10 degrees!

Answer (score -1):

Refering to the Triangle Problem 1 diagram: If z>=w then x=80-w+arctan[(tan(z+10)-tan(w+10))/(tan(10)^2-tan(z+10)*tan(w+10))] degrees. There is no general solution for x in terms of z and w without using trigonometry since some solutions for x require an infinite series of digits to the right of the decimal point.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).