# Basic geometry: find the angle

Tags: geometry

Question: Find $\angle BDE$ when
$\angle A=20^\circ$, $\overline{AB}=\overline{AC}$, $\angle CBD=65^\circ$, and $\angle BCE=25^\circ$.

[image: Figure]
So far I figured out that $\angle BDE=\angle AED-15^\circ$ and $\overline{BD}\bot\overline{CE}$ that don't seem to be helping.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/750410/worlds-hardest-easy-geometry-problem

Comment: @RobertZ Thanks a lot..!

Comment: @RobertZ I thought the answer that got the most votes to the post you mentioned was the answer you wanted me to look at but when I tried it I found it doesn't solve the problem (someone commented it gives only a linearly dependent equation system that's same to what I found). I don't see that the post you gave me has any real answer.

Comment: Try the external link: http://thinkzone.wlonk.com/MathFun/Triangle.htm This is a famous problem.

Comment: @RobertZ Thanks. I still don't see any solution there. The website owner is offering that if someone sends an e-mail then he might send back the answer. However, it seems that the solution is dependent to specific angles, but those two problems in the website have different angles than this one. Did you actually take a look at the external page and see what it's saying? Do you know the solution??

Comment: I gave a solution using trigonometry. I hope it helps.

Comment: Search for "adventitious angles".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a variation of the notorious [Langley's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langley%E2%80%99s_Adventitious_Angles).

We follow a trigonometric approach. Let $\angle BDE=x$.

i) Use the [Law of sines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines) in $\triangle EBC$, 
$$\frac{\sin 25^\circ}{EB}=\frac{\sin75^\circ}{AB}.$$

ii) Use the [Law of sines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines) in $\triangle DBC$, 
$$\frac{\sin 80^\circ}{BD}=\frac{\sin 35^\circ}{AB}.$$

iii) Use the [Law of sines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines) in $\triangle EBD$, 
$$\frac{\sin x}{EB}=\frac{\sin (165^\circ-x)}{BD}=\frac{\sin (15^\circ+x)}{BD}.$$

It follows that
$$\frac{\sin (15^\circ+x)}{\sin x}=\frac{\sin 80^\circ}{\sin 35^\circ}\cdot  \frac{\sin 75^\circ}{\sin 25^\circ}$$
Since $\sin (15^\circ+x)=\sin 15^\circ\cos x+\cos 15^\circ\sin x$, 
we obtain that
$$\cot x=\frac{1}{\sin 15^\circ}\cdot\frac{\sin 80^\circ}{\sin 35^\circ}\cdot  \frac{\sin 75^\circ}{\sin 25^\circ}-\cot 15^\circ.$$
Therefore $x=5^\circ$.

Answer (score 1):

This is the general solution for any angle:
[image]